# Retrieve records from Azure Table Storage is throwing Object Reference not set

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have very simple code to retrieve all items from Table Storage. Below code is failing with Object Reference not set exception

```
    public async Task<List<StringInternTableEntity>> GetAllRowsAsync()
    {
        var entities = new List<StringInternTableEntity>();

        try
        {
            TableContinuationToken token = null;
            do
            {
                var queryResult = await this.azureCloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(new TableQuery<StringInternTableEntity>(), token);
                entities.AddRange(queryResult.Results);
                token = queryResult.ContinuationToken;
            } while (token != null);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return entities;
    }

public class StringInternTableEntity : TableEntity
{
    public StringInternTableEntity()
    {
    }

    public StringInternTableEntity(string runStartTimeStamp, string wordKey)
    {
        PartitionKey = runStartTimeStamp;
        RowKey = wordKey;
    }

    public int NumberValue { get; set; }
}
```

"   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.Extensions.TableExtensionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass24_0`2.<<ExecuteQuerySegmentedInternalAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.Extensions.TableExtensionRetryPolicy.<ExecuteUnderRetryPolicy>d__2`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at Citadel.Common.Utils.AzureCloudTableHelper.d__9.MoveNext() in C:\Users\kalsa\source\repos\Citadel3\Citadel.Common\Utils\AzureCloudTableHelper.cs:line 166"

[image]

Also in my table I have 1 simple entry.
[image]

Comment: Could you post your `StringInternTableEntity` model?

Comment: @TấnNguyên - Updated.

Comment: As a quick look, I think `new TableQuery<StringInternTableEntity>()` cause the problem because it created new instance all time. Try to move it outside the loop.

Comment: Nope. Same issue. I tried the code mentioned below too, same error.

Comment: Then you might put the break point around `azureCloudTable`, it could be wrong somewhere because below code worked with me.

Answer (score -1):

You may try the below code where I have modified the logic for retrieval of data and finally storing it into the list

```
 public async Task<List<StringInternTableEntity>> GetAllRowsAsync()
        {
             var query = this.azureCloudTable.CreateQuery<StringInternTableEntity>();
                var result = new List<StringInternTableEntity>();
                var token = new TableContinuationToken();
                do
                {
                    var segment = await this.azureCloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, token);
                    token = segment.ContinuationToken;
                    result.AddRange(segment);
                } while (token != null);
                List<StringInternTableEntity> lstClientID = new List<StringInternTableEntity>();
                foreach (StringInternTableEntity codeMapping in result)
                {
                    lstClientID.Add(codeMapping);
                }
                return lstClientID;
        }
```

Comment: @MickyD I have added description of what I have done in answer. Please upvote in case you downvoted for that reason

Comment: Thanks for update. Wasn't me who downvoted but here is an upvote just the same.  **Moderators:** please ignore flag

Comment: @RaghvenderKataria - No Luck.Only thing that is different as you can see my screenshots, I have Partition Key which is timestamp based and Row Key is the actual Key.